# Nasty iOS SIGABRT error on addSubView - even on older snapshots and backup versions that used to work?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I had my ipad app working fine (using Xcode 4.2 ios5 beta 7), started adjusting the Settings.bundle and then suddenly I got a SIGABRT error on an addSubView command that had worked fine for me for weeks.

After an hour of wrestling with the problem, I figured "screw it, I'll go to my last snapshot that I know was working well". Pulled that up - same problem!

I've tried all of the following:

1) Went back 4 snapshots (about 2 days back) - all of them had the same error, despite the fact that I took the snapshots when the app was in good working state. (Note: Restoring snapshots never seems to work for me (i.e. no changes after restore), so I go into the Organizer and export out a  full separate copy of the snapshot and go from there).

2) Went back into my daily backup and pulled up a copy (about a day old) that the backup had caught. Same exact problem.

3) From the Xcode Organizer, wiped the Derived Data.

4) Restarted my laptop (also of course, restarting Xcode and the iOS Simulator) about 3 times.

5) Reset the iOS Simulator.

6) Reinstalled Xcode 4.2 ios 5 beta 7.

7) Even though it's totally illogical (because the XIB files should be separate and different in each backup), rebuilt the XIB files for the view that was crashing when I was adding it to my subView.

8) Tried to open it in Xcode 4.2 ios 5 beta 2 - it never finishes ATTACHING during the BUILD & RUN.

9) When I experimented and switch the addSubView to ANY other view, my app would NOT crash (so that was mildly encouraging), so I tried removing the only elements (i.e. activity indicator and UIWebView and UIPageControl) that were unique to the actual view I wanted to add as a subview (on the vague theory that some small element was corrupted in my XCode setup).

None of the above worked  Anyone have any ideas what kind of problem would cause this kind of crash across multiple copies of the same project?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the problem exhibit itself on the device?

Comment: Ahhhhhh ... indeed the problem does NOT happen on an actual iPad! 

Now, what does THAT mean?

Comment: Could you post what's being shown on the log? (any exception being thrown...)

Comment: @JavierSoto :  I don't get much in the way of log comments, but here's a screenshot of the breakpoint where the exception gets thrown and a screenshot of the final SIGABRT error:  

https://img.skitch.com/20110910-1b45kxw5gngwu7mgx72tcapgqn.jpg  

https://img.skitch.com/20110910-tfsx7ft43dt6muqs99237rd3rf.jpg

Comment: @AlastairStuart:  One thing your comment made me think of was that ALL versions/snapshots of my app seem to be writing cache and data files to the same exact place ( ~/Library/ApplicationSupport/iPhone SImulator/5.0/Applications/#####-####-#### and those files stay there even after a CLEAN and even after I reset the Simulator to default settings (or delete the app from the Simulator).

Comment: So that's ONE thing all of these snapshots share in common (and would actually explain why they ALL seem to use the same Default.png image as a startup image even when I erase it from the project).  I tried deleting those files and it didn't actually solve the problem, but perhaps that was one contributing factor.

Comment: On your screenshot it says "stopped at Breakpoit". Although you don't have one there, could you go to the break points tab, select all of them and delete them?

Answer (score 1):

Is the chamdashViewController_ included in a nib file?

It looks like the view you're referencing might not exist yet - a dangling pointer. Set a breakpoint and see if the aplicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions: method is called before your loadView method.

Alternatively, you could set a breakpoint before adding the subview and, in the debugger console, use the command "po [chamdashViewController_ view]" to make sure it's pointing to a live object.